# what does kkkk mean in Portuguese?

Tags: tradução

We received feedback from our Portuguese user, but we couldn't understand what does he/she mean, even we translate to English with google translate, will please someone explain to us?

The original feedback was:

> primeiro a avaliar kkkkk kkkkk decha o "sim" aqui em baixo kkkk

[image]

Answer (score 11):

A series of Ks is the way that laughter is generally represented in Brazilian Portuguese. It is akin to *hahaha* or *hehe* or *lolol* etc, in English, such that the longer it is the more the laughter.

Furthermore the automatic translator is stumbling because they write "decha" instead of "deixa", so the second bit was intended to be "leave a yes under here".

Comment: Furthermore, that's because one of the ways of depicting laughter in an exaggerated manner, especially in old comic book settings is "quáquáquáquá"

Answer (score 0):

IT's similar as "Lol", "LMAO", "hahaha" or another ways to laught.

Comment: Wellington, a tua resposta não acrescente nada à resposta mais votada

Answer (score -3):

it's just "hahahaha" to speakers of Brazilian Portuguese, it's also the same in the japanese language.

Comment: Welcome to our community, Alex! :) To improve your answer, can you explain a bit better how "kkkkk" is "hahahahaha", and what "hahahahaha" is? (The asker might not know what it is.) You could explain if it is idiomatic, or a phonetic representation, or an onomatopoea, etc.